# Several Android software sensors disabled after upgrade to 4.0

Tags: accelerometer, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-sensors

I recently updated my HTC Desire S to Ice Cream Sandwich (Android 4.0) using the RUU found on [HTCdev](http://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/downloads). Previous to this upgrade all sensors compatible with 2.3 worked just fine. After the upgrade the only sensors *working* are:

```
- Accelerometer
- Light sensor
- Magnetic field sensor
- Microphone
- Orientation sensor
- Proximity sensor
```

This poses a problem, as I need the linear accelerometer for a project. I have to no avail tried finding a solution to this problem. There have been some similar problems with xperia it seems, but overall I cannot seem to find a solution to this problem, or any places to download software patches that might help. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The list of sensors that SHOULD be included for 4.0 can be seen [here](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/en//compatibility/4.0/android-4.0-cdd.pdf)